# how to call function on complete execution of inner AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have AJAX code as mentioned below:

```
$("#id").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    url: 'url1',    
    type: 'get',
    data: {
        method: 'method1',
        param: id
    },
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function(p){
        let arr = [];
        const obj = JSON.parse(p);
        if (obj.RETVAL == true) {
            var i;
            for(i=0; i< 6 ; i++){
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'url2',    
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {
                        method: 'method2',
                        param: id2
                        },
                    success: function(r){
                        if (r>1) {
                        }
                        else{
                            arr.push(r);  //this array will be passed in fun1
                        }
                    }
                }); 
            }
        }
        fun1(arr);
    }
});
```

});

In my case what I noticed is fun1 is being called before the complete execution of code inside for loop. Like if for loop executed ones and the functions gets triggered. Because of this arr contains lesser entries. How can I call function fun1 only after complete execution of loop?

Answer (score 0):

`$.ajax` returns a [thenable](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/thenable).

Collect them in an array. Pass that array to [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). Call `fun1` when the promise returned by `Promise.all` resolves.